# How To Seprate Email and Number In Php

Tags: php

What I need :

Parse a string such as:

```
purchasing@is.com3940602685554
```

The problem I'm facing:

> **`I cannot parse domain name and number`**

What I have tried so far:

```
$myString = ' purchasing@isdaf.com3940602685554 ';
$myArray = explode('.', $myString);
print_r($myArray);
```

My Goal:

HTML code:

```
   <select multiple id="e2" name="team[]" style="width:300px">
   <option value=" purchasing@is.com3940602685554 ">Purchasing</option>
```

I have to insert the domain name and id another field.

So my query would be like:

```
    $team=$_POST['team'];
    teamname=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['teamname']);

   foreach ($team as $t) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO teamname(People_Name,User_id,Team_Name) VALUES ('".$t[0]."','".$t[1]."','".$teamname."')" ;
  }
```

Comment: put a separator between `email` and `number` (e.g., `|`) and explode on basis of that separator.

Comment: Is that how you want it to work? Or are you trying to separate the number?

Comment: ya i have domain nad and id no i have insert both values in diffrent  filed in datbse

Comment: out put with seprator is Array ( [0] => purchasing@i.com3940602685554 )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try regular expressions

```
$string = "purchasing@is.com3940602685554";
preg_match('/^(.+\.[a-z]{2,4})([0-9]+)$/', $string, $matches);
$email = $matches[1]; //purchasing@is.com
$number = $matches[2]; //3940602685554
```

Or if you want only domain name try

```
$string = "purchasing@is.com3940602685554";
preg_match('/^.+\@([a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]{2,4})([0-9]+)$/', $string, $matches);
$domain = $matches[1]; //is.com
$number = $matches[2]; //3940602685554

echo $domain;
echo $number;
```

---

And if you want to insert into DB Try

```
foreach ($team as $t) {
    preg_match('/^(.+\.[a-z]{2,4})([0-9]+)$/', $t, $matches);
    $email = $matches[1];
    $number = $matches[2];

    $query = "INSERT INTO teamname(People_Name,User_id,Team_Name) VALUES('".$email."','".$number."','".$teamname."')" ;
}
```

Comment: no output from your code

Comment: because you need output it using **echo** as second example

Comment: out put is is.com3940602685554

Comment: try `var_dump($matches);`

Comment: my concern is that i have insert the value in database

Comment: please check my updated code and  give solution

Comment: i don't understand what you want to do,
if you use my code, you'll have variables `$domain` and `$number` and you should use them in insert statement

Comment: let me explain $team=$_POST['team']; where team is array: print_r:ArrayArray ( [0] => operons@is.com8233122625718 [1] => installn@is.com8182649773418 [2] => fabrication@is.com8182649773412 [3] => mi@isdaf.com3941009580434 )

Comment: your code is  preg_match('/^(.+\.[a-z]{2,4})([0-9]+)$/', $team, $matches);
//     echo $email = $matches[1]; //purchasing@is.com
//    echo $number = $matches[2];

Comment: Yes, and what you need to insert into DB `operons@is.com` and `8233122625718` OR `is.com` and `8233122625718` OR what?

Comment: i have insert  operons@is.com and 8233122625718

Comment: @user3703097 look at my last edit, it should work

Comment: umnark my question for negative polls and i dont understand why people have mark post as unsefull

Comment: @user3703097 i don't give you negative vote

Comment: sr i dont undrstand why peopl are givng negative on this question does is seems bad question from your point of view i been faced issue first time

Comment: i think, that your first post was bad formated, and then they give that feedback on it

Answer (score 1):

try with **`preg_match()`**

```
$str = 'purchasing@is.com3940602685554';
 preg_match_all('/([a-zA-Z@.]+)([0-9]+)/', $str, $matches);
echo  $domain = $matches[1][0];//urchasing@is.com
echo  $number = $matches[2][0]; //3940602685554
```

or

```
 $str = 'purchasing@is.com3940602685554';
 preg_match('/([a-zA-Z@.]+)([0-9]+)/', $str, $matches);
 echo  $domain = $matches[1]; //urchasing@is.com
 echo  $number = $matches[2]; //3940602685554
```

Comment: And what if email contains `-`, `_` or another special character?

Comment: both answer output urchasing@is.com3940602685554

Comment: @Unlink answered according to what is asking

Comment: output is not change it same urchasing@is.com3940602685554

Comment: @user3703097 echo $matches[1][0];//urchasing@is.com
 echo $matches[2][0]; //3940602685554 both are different variables so waht you need output

Comment: @user3703097 try echo $matches[1][0]; echo "<br>"; echo $matches[2][0];

Comment: @user3703097 understand now it's two different variables output both has different output so use $domain for domain name and for number use $number

Comment: @Unlink yes same i think :)

Comment: please check my updated code i have explained my concer in more details

Answer (score -1):

Use this code..If you only targeting .com

```
  $string = "purchasing@is.com3940602685554";
preg_match('/^(.+\.[a-z]{2,4})([0-9]+)$/', $string, $matches);
$emailID = $matches[1];
$Contact = $matches[2];

echo $emailID."<br/>";
echo $Contact;
```